# SQL feasibility: possible to extrude rows by value and combine tables in custom fashion?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have the following sql table:

```
// foo

// columns 
ID 
DATE
SIZE
LIFETIME
```

Where `foo` represents the size and date when the object was deleted from the drive.

Suppose I have a second table,

```
// bar
ID
DATE
SIZE
```

Where bar is just a table with, for each day the particular object was on the drive (and coverage may be incomplete here), information about the object's size on **that day only**.

---

Right now, I am doing the following outside of SQL queries, and it is very time consuming: for each ID in foo, extrude the last known size into "LIFETIME" rows (where 1 row becomes N rows for lifetime N, with the last known size).

Then, I update the size values for each timestep with information from the `bar` table, per ID, when it is available for the particular timestep.

---

Can this computation be performed in a SQL query?  In other words: will it or wont it be a waste of time to look into?

---

---

By hand example, using integers rather than days for simplicity:

```
// foo initial
ID DATE SIZE LIFETIME
a,1000,20.5,2
b,500,40.8,4

// foo after "extrusion" with last known size value
ID DATE SIZE LIFETIME
a,1000,20.5,2
a,999,20.5,1
a,998,20.5,0
b,500,40.8,4
b,499,40.8,3
b,498,40.8,2
b,497,40.8,1
b,496,40.8,0


// bar initial
ID DATE SIZE
a,998,2.0
b,499,34.0
b,498,30.0
b,496,10.0
```

And the final, `foobar` data:

```
// foobar combined
ID DATE SIZE LIFETIME
a,1000,20.5,2
a,999,20.5,1
a,998,2.0,0
b,500,40.8,4
b,499,34.0,3
b,498,30.0,2
b,497,40.8,1 // if this could have the least neighboring size value with id b
b,496,10.0,0 // that would be amazing, but thought this would be a good start

// defining least neighboring size value: 
//    Given
c,26,72 // obj c @ time 35 with size 72
c,23,35 // obj c @ time 23 with size 35

// then the extrusion would be:
c,26,72,j
c,25,35,j-1
c,24,35,j-2
c,23,35,j-3
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What do you mean by "extrude" (it is not a database term)?  How is the object identified?  And tag your question with the database you are using.  Is the last known size from `bar` or `foo`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff will do; I'll will do a by hand conversion with simple data (and this is a simplification of my actual problem, but an answer here will be more than enough).

Comment: SQL is pretty well suited to identifying the last known SIZE for each ID in `bar`.

Comment: @ScottHunter i think this may be possible with SQL, I just don't have enough experience with it, and need to decide whether to optimize outside or do it in SQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff added a "by-hand" description of what I'm trying to do here -- had attempted a psuedo code description, but I am just not experienced enough in SQL to even get close without biasing towards something else.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Snowflake

Comment: What does "least neighboring size value" mean?

Comment: He just wants to densify and guarantee one row per day.

Comment: @ScottHunter updated with an explanation at the end

Comment: Is there a reason all of this redundant data needs to go in a table, as opposed to being generated on the fly?  That is, what are you *doing* with this data?

Comment: @ScottHunter I am generating it on the fly.  But I need to know if it is necessary to develop an efficient approach for use at scale, because the data becomes very large and it is not efficient without a level of effort and home-cooked code that I would like to avoid if possible, that is the **only** reason. Otherwise, yeah, I have a solution for on the fly generation.

Comment: Populating a table you don't need is not an efficient approach, at scale or not.

Comment: I think "extrapolation" may be the word you wanted rather than "extrusion".

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you for the answer by the way.  Anyhow, it would be interpolation in this case, and only if I used some kind of statistical model to do it.  Whereas extrusion is a term that implies a continuation of the observed slope, curve, data pattern etc. with no interpolation or extrapolation (this is exactly what is going on here).  For example, extending a curve or a surface along the instantaneous slope in a CAD/CAM system is an extrusion.

Comment: Fair enough. That's a term I wasn't familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with numbers as (select n from ...), /* values from 1 to max necessary */
select *
from foo f inner join numbers z on z.n <= f.lifetime
    cross apply (
        select top 1 size from bar b
        where b.id = f.id and f.date <= z.n
        order by z.n desc
    ) s
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, if possible